# Get data from upstream job in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline that is triggered by an upstream job. The upstream creates a file with a string in it. I want to be able to access that string from the pipeline. Is there a way to get the data about the upstream job required to read the file, from within the Groovy sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "step" "copy artifacts from another project".

It will look like the following:

```
step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: '**/myFile.txt',
      fingerprintArtifacts: true, flatten: true, projectName: "myProject-job-name",
      selector: [$class: 'StatusBuildSelector', stable: true]])
```